# Direct Parameter access being ignored

Tags: c, printf

So my line of code goes as followed

```
printf("test @ 0x%1$08x = %2$d 0x%2$08x\n", &test_val, test_val);
```

but instead of printing the variables it's printing

```
test @ 0x$08x = $d 0x$08x
```

It's completely ignoring the percent character and not printing out any variable. I can't find anything on this or any reason why this might happen hopefully someone can help.

> EDIT: I could not find a link but basically from my knowledge and from
>   [*Hacking: The art of Exploitation*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441) the number after the percent character should be the parameter it uses so %n$d would use the nth
>   parameter and print as a decimal. in this case %1$08x would print
>   &test_val in hexadecimal and %2$d would print test_val as a decimal.

Comment: Could you please post a link explaining how printf is supposed to interpret the parameters that you pass?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, printing `test @ 0xa2dd9f3c = 291 0x00000123`. Please provide more info: compiler, OS, platform, minimal example of code that doesn't work but can be compiled. Looks like compiler issue to me.

Answer (score -1):

```
int c = 0;
int * p = &c;

printf("test@ 0x%d  %d\n", &p, *p);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/
Have a look at this page to know which modifiers will have which course.

> (number)  Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces. The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

Comment: I'm sorry if i wasn't clear but that's not what i was confused about. I know how to control the minimum characters that can be printed but i was doing something called direct parameter access where you can choose which parameter to draw the value from. that's what the $ was for and the number preceding the $ was the parameter to be printed

Comment: Printing a pointer with %d isn't portable - e.g. it won't work on 64-bit Windows. (Also, 0x%d prints in decimal but makes it look like it should be hex)